# Can't fix with 405 allowed POST filter Java

Tags: java, spring

Now I have such problem, after creating filter((The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

Please try again in 30 seconds.

```
package com.lumiin.mytalk.filter;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.info("Adding Access Control Response Headers");
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
    enter code here
    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code instead of image of code?

Comment: Sure, see! I pasted there!

Comment: Your `doFilter` method is hanging in the air - it should be an overriden method of `Filter` class. Otherwise it won't work like you expect.

Comment: If I create filter for that?

Comment: @AlexUl I think you should create a filter

Comment: Updated error. See

Comment: where is the error message?

Comment: What is the problem now? Is there any stack trace or something?

Comment: In repsonse in browser

Comment: OPTIONS http://6.taxi2deals.appspot.com/app/taxi/v1/getAll/ByGeoLocation 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: POST 
Content-Type: application/json
405 Method Not Allowed
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  *
access-control-allow-credentials:  true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:  POST, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-headers:  Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
Content-Language:  en-US
Allow:  GET, HEAD
X-Cloud-Trace-Context:  59fa9306a865a98afcaaac40f25ef0b3;o=1
Date:  Fri, 24 Feb 2017 15:48:21 GMT
Content-Type:  text/html
Server:  Google Frontend
Content-Length:  0

Comment: that is response of browser

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://6.taxi2deals.appspot.com/app/taxi/v1/getAll/ByGeoLocation. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://taxi2deals.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Now status ok, but it is now.

Comment: Try to modify your question a bit so that it won't be difficult to follow what exactly you are facing